# Seven term Blackman Harris window

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, window-functions

I am currently trying to evaluate a high resolution ADC for which I need to window my output data for the FFT. Up until now I have been using the default 4 term Blackman harris window in MATLAB. However, I came across a few app notes that recommend using a seven term Blackman Harris for the SNR ranges that I am interested in.
I have tried looking quite a bit but I cannot seem to find an equation for implementing the seven term BH window, neither is it available in MATLAB. Can someone point me to a source where I can find this? 
As far as I am aware Harris' classic paper on windows doesn't provide the equation either.

Comment: In addition to the complete answer that was provided, I have found [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/bhiksha/WWW/courses/dsp/spring2013/WWW/schedule/readings/windows_comparison2_harris.pdf) and [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/752e/4232eeb19a880bdd63bef78b554974627c15.pdf) paper useful when thinking about windows.

Comment: I wrote this function for a few different windows including the blackmanharris 7 term: https://github.com/Matlab-Toolbox/create_window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this document](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370371K-01/lvsmt/smt_calculate_correction/) you can find the coefficients of a seven-term Blackman Harris window. Ignoring the bizarre notation, it seems like the window is defined by

$$w[n]=\sum_{k=0}^6a_k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}\right),\quad n=0,1,\ldots,N-1\tag{1}$$

where $N$ is the window length and the coefficients $a_k$ are given by

$$\begin{align}
a_0&=0.27105140069342\\
a_1&= - 0.43329793923448\\a_2&=0.21812299954311\\a_3&= - 0.06592544638803\\a_4&=  0.01081174209837\\a_5&= - 0.00077658482522\\a_6&=  0.00001388721735\end{align}
$$

Unfortunately, they do not mention where those coefficients come from. Somebody must have run an optimization routine to minimize the sidelobe level for a given mainlobe width.

---

EDIT:

I think I found the relevant paper [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/940309/). [This](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/46092/versions/3/previews/coswin.m/index.html?access_key=) is a corresponding Matlab function.